# Laravel 5 prepend to parent view section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm writing a webpage using Laravel 5.0 and would like to modularize sections of a view.
Currently I have master >> view >> partial templates.

> **master.blade.php**
>
> ```
> <head>
>     <!-- master's css -->
>     @yield('css')
> </head>
> <body>
>     @yield('content')
> </body>
> ```
>
> **view.blade.php**
>
> ```
> @extends('master')
> @section('css')
>     <!-- view-specific css -->
> @stop
> @section('content')
>     <!-- some content -->
>     @include('partial')
> @stop
> ```
>
> **partial.blade.php**
>
> ```
> @section('css')
>     @parent
>     <!-- partial-specific css -->
> @append
>
> <!-- partial's content -->
> ```

How it loads:

> ```
> <head>
>     <!-- master's css -->
>     <!-- view-specific css -->
>     <!-- partial-specific css -->
> </head>
> ```

How I want it to load:

> ```
> <head>
>     <!-- master's css -->
>     <!-- partial-specific css -->
>     <!-- view-specific css -->
> </head>
> ```

I've tried moving the `@parent` before and after the `view-specific css` but the page loads the `partial-specific css` after the view css regardless.

My reasoning is that I'd like to have the last css sheet from the view template to be the last loaded so that I may overwrite some of the partial's css if needed for a particular page that uses it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you're using `@append`

Comment: I attempted to use `@stop` and `@overwrite` but the desired results were not achieved.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be for `partial` to extend `view`:

**Master**

```
<head>
    <!-- master's css -->
    @yield('css')
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
```

**View**

```
@extends('master')
@section('css')
    <!-- view-specific css -->
@stop
@section('content')
    <!-- some content -->
@stop
```

**Partial**

```
@extends('view')
@section('css')
    <!-- partial-specific css -->
    @parent
@stop

@section('content')
    @parent
    <!-- partial's content -->
@stop
```

And your output would be:

```
<head>
    <!-- master's css -->
    <!-- partial-specific css -->
    <!-- view-specific css -->

</head>
<body>
        <!-- some content -->

<!-- partial's content -->
</body>
```

And instead of `return view('view');`
you would `return view('partial');`

It may not make sense in your situation to do it this way, but you will get the desired results.

Comment: That's how I'd normally do it. However, I plan to use this partial in at least a few different pages so I'd like it to be as independent of the parent view as possible. The parent view should be used for customizing the style of the partial to the view in which it is being displayed. Thank you. I'm thinking I'll need to experiment with a new yield() in the master.